# Update with join that will work on both MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I need this update/join query to work on both MySQL and SQL Server.  I just can't seem to figure it out. I'm not sure if it's even possible.  Here's what it looks like

```
update table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
set a.name = b.name
```

Can anyone help me change that in a way that it will work on both MySQL and SQL Sserver? Thanks!

Comment: Normally, when you have code that must work on multiple DBs, it's better to write dedicated queries for each one, using each one particular features and syntax.

Comment: Why did my post get a -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correlated subqueries instead of a `join`:

```
update table1 a
    set a.name = (select b.name from table2 b where a.id = b.id)
    where exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.id = b.id);
```

The outer `where` clause is not necessary if you know that the ids match in the two tables.

Comment: This work.  However, i was wondering if there are any other ways? The reason is the MySQL version i'm using is old and i cannot use "select" inside brackets

Comment: @user15364266 . . . Of course it can.  The only limitation is that the two tables have to be different.  But this is the only version that would work in both MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle you can write following query, I am not sure if it works on MySQL and SQL Server too or not:

```
update (select a.name n1, b.name n2
          from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id)
   set n1 = n2
```

Comment: Why post an answer when you aren't sure its correct???